# How can I extract in excel certain strings that begin with a word from a row that contains multiple strings delimited by commas?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following row in excel: ['milk', 'milk with honey','bread','milk with bread','butter','milk with butter']
I want to be able to extract all the strings that begin with the word "milk" either on separate columns or in the same column.
The extract should look like: milk, milk with honey, milk with bread, milk with butter.

Comment: What have you tried so far? 
You can use `FIND` or VBA to loop through the string and extract programmatically.

Comment: I tried "text to column" in excel and then flagged them somehow, but the list is enormous, I have over 1000 columns if I were to split them using "text to column". The thing is that I don't know the combinations, I only know that there are strings that begin with a certain word and I need to extract all those strings. Taking my example -  I don't know that that there is "milk with honey", I need to extract the entire string as it begins with "milk". Only "milk" is known. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: The first two strings are delimited by both a comma and a space. THe rest of the strings are only delimited by commas. Is that true or is it a typo? Also do the quotes and the brackets exist in the original string or did you add them? Finally, it'd be nice to post the code you've already tried and the issues you're having with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough scetch of an VBA approach. Obviously you gotta fit it into an appropriate loop to apply for the whole sheet. Maybe there need to be some more error handling, but it should give you an idea:

```
Sub extract_string()

Dim l As Long
Dim search_string As String
Dim next_item As Integer
Dim next_col As Integer

search_string = Cells(1, 1).Value

For l = 1 To Len(search_string) 'loop through string

    If (Mid(search_string, l, 4) = "milk") Then 'check, if milk

        On Error GoTo Last_Item
        next_item = WorksheetFunction.Find(",", search_string, l + 1)

        next_col = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1 'find end

        If (next_item <> 0) Then

            Cells(1, next_col).Value = Mid(search_string, l, next_item - l)

        Else
Last_Item:
            Cells(1, next_col + 1).Value = Mid(search_string, l, Len(search_string) - l + 1) 'last item handling

        End If

    End If

next_item = 0

Next l

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, I will assume that your initial string looks like this:

> milk,milk with honey,bread,milk with bread,butter,milk with butter

...and that it's stored in `cell A1` of a worksheet named `Sheet1`.

The first thing I would do to make my life easier, would be to use `Text to Columns` and define `comma` as the delimiter. This would split your initial string into as many cells as it needs, the first one being stored in `A1`.

Then, to find which of the individual strings start with the word `milk` and combine them to one new string named `output`, I would do the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub milk()
Dim output As String
Dim inputRng As Range, cell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
output = ""
With sht
    Set inputRng = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
End With
For Each cell In inputRng.Cells
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "milk") = 1 Then
        output = output & cell.Value & ", "
    End If
Next cell
MsgBox output
End Sub
```